# IPhone 4 iOS 7.1.2

Tags: iphone

I can't update my apps. I click on the update button and it asks for my Apple ID the just changes back to update. Iv tapped it several times and just goes back to update button. Iv force reset my phone a few times doesn't work either. I don't know what to do because my apps won't let me open them until there updated. Please help?

Comment: normally apps will not prevent you from using them if they are not updated, they will remind you. So what app is not working?, as forthe AppleID, does it work in iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you're connected to WiFi to update the apps.

Second, are the other apps updating without any issues? If so, try uninstalling the troublesome app(s) and reinstalling them.

If none of those options work, try logging out of your iCloud account (under Settings App > iCloud, or under Settings App > App Store) then signing back in; it could be an issue with authenticating your credentials with Apple's servers.

A thought: are you using the same Apple ID (with which you bought the apps) to update the apps?

Hope this helps!